# Why is customizing paragraphs in flutter a pain?

Tags: flutter, text-widget

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days. I want to display a few university lessons in a flutter app. I used the Text widget, but it's not sufficiently customizable. If I want to make one single word bold in the entire paragraph, I can't do that. I tried the RichText widget, but that was a pain in the neck, I would have to create a new TextSpan everytime I want to customize a piece of the paragraph somehow.

Before you say markdown, I gave that a try too. But I can't change the font size, it's small and not so easy on the eyes. I did check the docs on Github, but there doesn't seem to be enough flexibility, you can't resize or align text.

I am left with one option, which is to use an HTML view plugin. I tried importing that, but now it's giving me an error.

If you know any tricks on how to customize text, hopefully within flutter, not using HTML/markdown, I would really appreciate it. Any suggestions on how to make my life easier are welcome!

Comment: RichText is the way to go. There is not that much difference to HTML where you'd need a `<span>` or similar to be able to assign a different style for a word. You can of course use webview with HTML which is now available as an inline widget.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html might be worth a look.

Comment: I ended up using markdown. I found a workaround to change the fontsize.

Comment: Here's my answer to another question that states how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175783/flutter-flutter-markdown-fontsize/53486272#53486272